# Using appDelegate to fill an array of other class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that have database based on XML structure. XML is quite large, and what i want is, to parse it from very beginning, and then fill array that declared in other class. That is how i try to do this - when parsing ended, method -`(void)dataFromXMLdidFinishExtractingToArray:(NSMutableArray*)array`:  is called through protocol, then i want to fill an array. Please, take a look at my code, that declared in appDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    dataManager *dataMgr =[[dataManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self];
    [dataMgr loadInternalData];
    return YES;
}

-(void)dataFromXMLdidFinishExtractingToArray:(NSMutableArray*)array{

    ListViewController *listController = [[ListViewController alloc]init];
    listController.listOfPlaceDetails = array;
    NSLog(@"%@ NAMES", array);
    NSLog(@"delegate Called");

}
```

Firstly, i do parsing with my dataManager class, and when it finish, trying to fill data in array. Parsing is just fine, i can see everything in console. But, when i load my listViewController class, array - self.listOfPlaceDetails is empty.  How can i pass values from appDelegate to other class in my app?

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Make sure the array which you are passing to dataFromXMLdidFinishExtractingToArray: in app delegate after parsing is allocated and initiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `ListViewController` which is not the one you are using in your view controllers hierarchy. Instead, you need to grab a reference to your initiated `ListViewController`.

Depending on your UI structure and navigation you use, it will be either your rootViewController or any of its child viewControllers.

Alternatively, you can use notification to inform your `ListViewController` when your data model has changed.